# 'Frame' object has no atrribute 'seek'

Tags: python, tkinter, docx

### Code:

```
#imports
import tkinter as tk
from docx import Document

win = tk.Tk()

mighty = tk.Frame(win)
mighty.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

mighty_doc = Document(mighty) # This creates the error
mighty_doc.add_heading('MIGHTY',0)

mighty_doc.save('mighty') #optional

win.mainloop()
```

### Goal:

I want display a document `docx` in a `tkinter` `Frame`, which means it will be its parent. Is this possible?

Comment: The `Document` class from `docx` module is not a `tkinter` widget subclass, so it cannot be shown in a `tkinter` `Frame`.

Comment: Oh, so It's not possible? Is there a way to accomplish something similar to this using `tkinter`?

Comment: Take a screenshot and make that into the pdf?